# What is the current impact of TARP (bank bailout) on US deficit?

Tags: united-states, budget, financing, financial-crisis

As far as I am aware, at least some of the money that was given by US Government under TARP was paid back to the government.

As such, how much of the ~$800 Billion was given back to the treasury and how much was not?

In other words, what is the contribution of TARP to budget deficit as of 1/1/2013?

(if you wish, for extra credit you can include side amounts such as interest paid on TARP borrowing by the Feds, on one hand - and the interest the financial institutions paid to the government on the money they got from TARP on the other. I doubt that either one would have a significant effect though).

Answer (score 2):

OK, based on [Daily TARP Update for 2/1/2013](http://www.treasury.gov/initiatives/financial-stability/reports/Documents/Daily%20TARP%20Update%20-%2001.02.2013.pdf) from US Treasury:

```
| ($Billions)        | Loaned | Repaid | Balance | Writeoff | Income | CashBack |
=====================+========+========+=========+==========+========+==========|
| Bank bailouts only | 250.46 | 234.00 | 16.46   | 3.15     | 6.65   | 268.16   |
| Total TARP paid    | 418.11 | 344.43 | 73.68   | 27.10    | 43.02  | 387.46   |
| TARP + AIG shares  | 418.11 | 344.43 | 73.68   | 27.10    | 60.58  | 405.01   |
```

Therefore, of $418 Billion TARP, the government was directly repaid $344.43 Billion ($73.68 balance), or $387 Billion if you include interest and other non-principal payments excluding AIG shares ($30.65 Billion balance). This drops to $13.1 Billion once AIG shares held by Treasury are included.

**Therefore, the total DIRECT TARP contribution to 2012 YE deficit was $13.1 Billion**, plus or minus pocket change of couple billion depending on if you trust governments valuation of some assets.

This figure would, however, rise slightly if you remember that TARP - all $418 Billion of it - contributed to deficit and therefore had to be borrowed. Therefore, the figure should theoretically include the borrowing costs of that $418.11B, which I didn't since I don't have a good schedule of repayments.

---

**NOTE1**: To clarify based on Chad's comments - I have included the "Writeoff" column *just for color*, but neither the "Balance" column (which I personally calculated simply as Loaned-Repaid), nor "CashBack" column (which I checked to be exactly "Repaid+Income"), include writeoffs as an asset. The only report column which included writeoffs as asset is "Outstanding", which I didn't use at all.

---

**NOTE2**:  In case someone is curious WHY there was extra income, as I aluded to in the last note, recall that - on top of simple interest and fees paid by TARP recipients - some of TARP was in the form of "Government paid for distressed assets, which were later sold off". As one example, [Maiden Lane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maiden_Lane_Transactions) transactions (Bear Stearns and AIG assets) netted the government **profits**:

> In a February 28, 2012 press release, the New York Fed announced that the remaining securities in ML II were sold, and will result in **full repayment of the $19.5 billion loan extended by the New York Fed to ML II** and **generate a net gain for the benefit of the public of approximately $2.8 billion, including $580 million in accrued interest on the loan**.
>
> On Thursday August 23, 2012, the Federal Reserve announced that Maiden Lane III had sold the last of its AIG portfolio that day. **The Fed had earned a profit of $17.7 billion from the AIG and related assets**. The bulk of all Fed profits are required by Fed rules be turned over to the U.S. Treasury. **The Treasury still held a 53 percent stake in AIG's stock which it planned to gradually sell in an effort to recover the remaining $24.2 billion investment** (*note* - the latter was part of the difference between lines 2 and 3 of my spreadsheet above).

Comment: The bonds are around 1.5% for the Tarp Period if you go long term... but no one is buying our long term debt... So you have to go to 3-4% that we are paying on our short term bonds that have to be turned around every 6-12 months.  You also just ignore the writeoff amount.  That is money that the governemtn has given up on ever being returned.

Comment: @Chad - I'm not ignoring writeoff. The Balance figure is Loaned-Repaid, and **not** "Outstanding" report column which would have included write-offs. neither does the cashback if you check the PDF's #s. Writeoffs are less than balance (as you'd intuitively expect) because there was extra income.

Comment: And the AIG shares are worth nothing more than the magnetic pulses that represent them until they are sold.

Comment: @Chad - did you even **read** the answer? I explicitly stated that: "plus or minus pocket change of couple billion depending on if you trust governments valuation of some assets". Given that most likely a majority of the money in your 401k/pension, assuming you have any, is the same "magnetic pulses" if you're invested into equity, you better hope they are not worthless.

Comment: AIG and GM stock are worthless.I would rather have facebook at least they have positive revenue.  I have been investing in farm land for 20 years.  I am not to worried about funding my retirement.

Comment: @Chad- Google Finance disagrees with you about worthlessness of both [AIG](https://www.google.com/finance?cid=1093) and [GM](https://www.google.com/finance?q=GM).

Comment: Try selling off all of the assets and watch what happens.  Until the shares are sold they are worthless.  I have suspicions that that significant Government Stake in the companies is causing some significant increase in valuation.  And that when the government stake falls low enough there will be a sharp drop in price.  Their numbers do not match up with their stock prices.  Especially GM

Comment: "Their numbers do not match up with their stock prices" != 
"worthless"

Comment: Maybe not but in the case of GM and AIG it is a distinction with no real difference.

Comment: @Chad - cite???